# Where is log of Wine?

Tags: linux, wine

Where I using `Windows`, I play `League of Legends` portable, just execute and play

I'm trying play this game in `Linux`, I'm using `Metamorphose Linux`, is a `debian` base distrution.

I'm try execute using `Wine`, is not working, but where can I find `Wine` erro log for me make a search in

Comment: its not in `dmesg`? run `dmesg | tail` right after encountering an error to see if it is logged in the debug log.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a League of Legends log file, try using [winefile](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/explorer-like-wine) to browse and locate it as you would in native Windows. If you are looking for actual Wine logs, the [Troubleshooting](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Troubleshooting) info should help. E.g. from section 9.1.1 at the previous link:

```
cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Games/Tron
wine tron.exe &> log.txt
```